# Check available status of XMPP user not in buddy list

Tags: xmpp, chat, xmppframework, tigase

I am working with XMPP iOS SDK and I need to get the `Presence` of a user that may or may not be in my buddy list.

Through `didReceivePresence` delegate method of SDK provides presence of only users that are already added in my buddy list.

Quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot receive presence that are not it your roster. This is per design in XMPP. You need to have the user approve the presence sharing.